# Python2 code runs correctly in terminal, but not when executed as Python3

Tags: putty

Below code waits for commands from Android Bluetooth Terminal (ie Blue Term): 0 (dim LED) or 1 (light LED).

1. When this program is ran in RPI Putty terminal as python 5EE-Bluetooth-LED.py it performs as designed.
   However when run as python3 5EE-Bluetooth-LED.py nothing happens.
   Why would that be abd what is needed to run as python3?
2. When this program is ran in Thonny, nothing happens either but I suspect that is because there too python3 is ran. Is that so, and how can this be solved?

When run as python3, the screen output is (after having entered first a "1" and then a "0" in the terminal:

Hello World

debug 1

debug 2

debug 3

debug 4

Accepted connecion from ('18:94:c6:95:de:0d', 1)

Received: b'1'

Received: b'0'

```py
print("Hello World")
import bluetooth
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO        #calling for header file which helps in using GPIOs of PI
LED=21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)     #programming the GPIO by BCM pin numbers. (like PIN40 as GPIO21)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(LED,GPIO.OUT)  #initialize GPIO21 (LED) as an output Pin
GPIO.output(LED,0)
print("debug 1")
server_socket=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
port = 0
print("debug 2")
server_socket.bind(("",port))
print("debug 3")
server_socket.listen(1)
print("debug 4")
client_socket,address = server_socket.accept()
print ("Accepted connection from ",address)
while 1:
 
   data = client_socket.recv(1024)
   print ("Received: %s" % data)
   if data == "0":    #if '0' is sent from the Android App, turn OFF the LED
        print ("GPIO 21 LOW, LED OFF")
        GPIO.output(LED,0)
   if data == "1":    #if '1' is sent from the Android App, turn OFF the LED
        print ("GPIO 21 HIGH, LED ON")
        GPIO.output(LED,1)
   if data == "q":
        print ("Quit")
        break
 
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: Add more debug print statements. Could be changes in libraries between python2 and python3.

Comment: I did per your suggestion. Result: on startup in python3 the code runs until and included server_socket.listen(1)
Once the bluetooth terminal is connected then execution until and included while(1).
And when a "1" is entered in the terminal then this is shown, and nothing else:
"Received: b'1'
Hence no execution of the subsequent if condition.

Comment: Edit your question with the new debug code, include the actual debug output.

Comment: "Edit your question with the new debug code, include the actual debug output."
Done.

Comment: SOLVED: the print output is b'1' or b'0' (why would that be?). So subsequently the if statement needs to change to if data == b'0' and if data == b'1'

Comment: A socket transfers transfers binary data, so .read() return bytes.

Comment: "Why would that (ie the Thonny shell output) be " b'1' " and " b'0' " "? Well this was due to the Bluetooth Serial Terminal in Android "Settings/Send/" "Newline" to "CR+LF", must be changed to "none".

Answer (score 1):

In python2:
b"0" == u"0"

In python3:
b"0" != u"0"

So your if statements don't match.

Probably best to do:

```
if data == "0":    #if '0' is sent from the Android App, turn OFF the LED
    print ("GPIO 21 LOW, LED OFF")
    GPIO.output(LED,0)
elif data == "1":    #if '1' is sent from the Android App, turn OFF the LED
    print ("GPIO 21 HIGH, LED ON")
    GPIO.output(LED,1)
elif data == "q":
    print ("Quit")
    break
else:
    print("Unknown command: "+repr(data))
```

Then you'll be able to work out a bit more about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html
```

Very trivial, and the change in the print-syntax is probably the most widely known change, but still it is worth mentioning: Python 2’s print statement has been replaced by the print() function, meaning that we have to wrap the object that we want to print in parantheses.

Python 2 doesn’t have a problem with additional parantheses, but in contrast, Python 3 would raise a SyntaxError if we called the print function the Python 2-way without the parentheses.

Python 2
print 'Python', python_version()
print 'Hello, World!'
print('Hello, World!')
print "text", ; print 'print more text on the same line'
Python 2.7.6
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
text print more text on the same line
Python 3
print('Python', python_version())
print('Hello, World!')

print("some text,", end="")
print(' print more text on the same line')
Python 3.4.1
Hello, World!
some text, print more text on the same line
print 'Hello, World!'
File "", line 1
print 'Hello, World!'
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Note:

Printing “Hello, World” above via Python 2 looked quite “normal”. However, if we have multiple objects inside the parantheses, we will create a tuple, since print is a “statement” in Python 2, not a function call.

print 'Python', python_version()
print('a', 'b')
print 'a', 'b'
Python 2.7.7
('a', 'b')
a b

Hope this helps